# Use Lo-Dash merge without modifying underlying object

Tags: javascript, lodash

How can I use lodash `_.merge(obj, source)` without `obj` being modified? I just want a return of the value that merge computes,but I want to keep my original object intact.

I assume this question applies to most lodash functions, but I haven't found a solution so far.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Simply provide an empty object as the target ([`merge` supports more than one `source` value](https://lodash.com/docs#merge)):

```
var result = _.merge({}, obj, source);
```

Comment: Sometimes I am really overwhelmed by the simplicity and beauty of the solution.

Comment: meanwhile, I'm left wondering why this function was implemented this way

Comment: @Boern 100% this is beautiful

Comment: @J-Cake :) 100% agree with you :D